# Question about negotiation for a job

Tags: job-offer

I was unhappy with a few elements of my role and looking into getting back into development. So, I have been looking for a new role. I secured an offer of a new job and accepted it, then handed in my resignation. Everything was set in this direction.

I was leaving because the company I work for is not a software company and I wanted to move in this direction for my career.

Now, two weeks after resigning, a part of my company was bought by a very large fruity company who are very much a software company. My position is included in this purchase - I am an in scope employee.

The new company is very interested in keeping me on as part of the purchased segment of my employer. This would give me many opportunities to progress software-wise. I serve many areas of the business, and the parts I dislike aren't being bought, just the parts which I develop software for.

My question is, do I mention any of this to my new employer? I will be getting an offer of a new job as a matter of course with the process of the purchase. It's all part of the Transfer of Employees from one organisation to the other.

I obviously did not initiate this process, but it does change the status quo as I will shortly have another offer of employment.

It would seem unprofessional to try to elicit a reaction but it's not like I went out of my way to get this job offer (I had nothing to do with the deal and everyone in my part of the business was quite surprised that we were being sold). And I'm only thinking about it because of the reputation of the purchasing company, and the fact it will be much more development based.

Comment: Hello, these questions seem relevant: 1. [Quitting a job after one month to join previous employer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/113195/9549), 2. [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/7149/9549), 3. [Does returning to a previous employer look bad on a resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/83595/9549)

Comment: You asked, "do I mention any of this to my new employer?" What would you hope to gain by doing that? Are you really thinking of whether or not to mention this to the new employer, or are you actually considering staying on with the purchaser of your old employer? Since you've already resigned, how is it possible that you even have a position at the purchasing company?

Comment: @dwizum There is some EU legislation covering continuous employment of employees, my notice period is 3 months and the purchase was announced two weeks after i handed it in. in this situation in the UK the new employeer will issue offers to all in scope employees, regardless of if you are set to let or not.

Answer (score 4):

You see opportunity with the company that is purchasing your old company.

What can be the big unknown is what the purchasing company will be doing with your old company. Are they buying the company for the product, for the market, for the customers, for the patents, or for the employees?

Some of those will be good for you, others will point to a short amount of time before you will be cast aside.

There are large unknowns about this yet un-offered employment: amount of pay, benefits, work location.

Yes work location. They could insist that everybody moves to one of their main sites. I saw that happen several times. A group was growing, the company was purchased; and the new company said, since you have to move to a new building anyway we have a nearly empty one 30 miles away. Now employees had to decide if that was still a good place to work.

Until you have that offer don't use it to get a reaction. Until they make the offer you have nothing to judge.

It can take weeks or months for those purchases to be approved. If you decide to reject the employment with the new company so you can wait for an offer from the purchasing company, realize that you could end up unemployed.

Comment: The buying company is buying both IP and employees. The work location is part of the purchase, they were buying a lot of product from us and so wish to do it all in house to make a better profit margin, I am part of the Silicon Test part of the business, which is why they want to buy this part as reducing test time is very important for silicon production.